# Insert rows after every new reference shows up in a column

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have data in a column and I am trying to run a macro so that a new row (a preset line) is inserted every time a new value is found.

Here is an example of how the data looks currently:

```
1   C   100
1   D   100
1   E   100
1   F   100
1   G   100
2   C   200
2   D   200
2   E   200
```

I want the macro to look in the first column and if there is a new value then insert a row (paste a predefined line)

This is the outcome:

```
1   C   100
1   D   100
1   E   100
1   F   100
1   G   100
Predefined line copied
2   C   200
2   D   200
2   E   200
Predefined line copied
```

My current code looks like this. It is not working:

```
Sub InsertCreditorLine()

'based on value in column AB, works out where new expense starts and inserts the creditor line formula row

Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim PrintArea1 As Variant
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

' works out last row to work up from

    Col = "AB"
    StartRow = 6
    BlankRows = 1

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With ActiveSheet
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1

'Looks to value in column AB to see where new expense starts

If .Cells(R, Col) = "Y" Then

'paste in line


Rows("1:13").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

.Cells(7, 7).EntireRow.Copy
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next R
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: `If .Cells(R, Col) = "Y" Then` you have numbers, why are you testing for `y`?

Comment: @findwindow probably a formula for checking if the previous line has a different value then the actual one (returns "y" if different)... still the question why to go till row 6 but unhide 1 to 13.

Comment: Oh. If true, that step can be eliminated.

Comment: Why is a line copied at the end (after `2 E 2001`)? I get the first copy as the value changes from `1` to `2`...

Comment: @AlexP guessing it changes to 3 but OP neglected to include that.

Comment: just change the code between `'paste in line` and `End If` to `.Rows(7).EntireRow.Copy` and `.Rows(R).EntireRow.Insert xlDown`. Still assuming the col "AB" does the check... also as it looks to me, it should work well as it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Sub InsertCreditorLine()
    Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long, presetRow As Range, rw As Long

    startRow = 6
    lastRow = Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set presetRow = Range("7:7")

    For rw = lastRow To startRow + 1 Step -1
        If Range("AB" & rw) <> Range("AB" & rw).Offset(-1, 0) Then
            presetRow.Copy
            Range("AB" & rw).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: It is as intended. I am comparing the current row to the next row by using `offset(-1, 0)` to look ahead one row.

Comment: Hello @alex-p, I am getting an error 1004 and it is stating that the copy paste area must be the same. I can confirm that all columns and rows are the same size.

Comment: Ok I was able to resolve the issue with the copy paste. Basically presetRow.Copy
            Range("AB" & rw).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
needs to be
presetRow.Copy
            Range("A" & rw).Insert Shift:=xlDown

However I ran into another issue. The last row is also unique so there needs to be a predefined row pasted below that too. The macro seems to pick up all the lines but does not account the last row.

So essentially the last row will always be the predefined row after the macro is done looping through.